# How to access static non-script files for use in nextflow processes

Tags: docker, cloud, conda, nextflow

How do I make sure that files needed for a process to run, but are not scripts, are available in nextflow processes when run on the cloud? In my case, this is a quarto document to render.

Scripts can be stored in the `bin` directory and will be made available on run time, but these are presumably made available to all processes, which is not ideal if the file is large. The `assets` directory is available to the launcher, but not the containerized processes, so directly calling `"${projectDir}/assets"` in the module does not work. Files can be embedded in docker containers, but then conda will not work and the files used would be determined by the docker container rather than the workflow source code repository.

Comment: If an input file is required for a Nextflow process, it should be provided through an input channel. That's how Nextflow knows it must stage the file in the task directory.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to store the files in the `assets/` directory, create a channel in the workflow that calls the module using `Channel.fromPath("${projectDir}/assets/my_folder_or_file", checkIfExists: true)`, and modify the module to accept this as an input.